# How to integerate credit card payment alone in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing a restaurant application in that i want to integerate credit card payment for ordered items.

Thanks.

Comment: what you had tried or search to achieve this.?

Comment: Hi@SilentKiller i am searching to apply in my app.

Comment: hint : *paypal payment, inapp purchase etc...*

Comment: Ok @SilentKiller i will try..Is it possible to create a credit payment like payTM App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many payment gateways that allow access to api's for mobile platforms these days, a few to get you started:

1. JudoPay: https://www.judopay.com/docs
2. PayPal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/
3. Payscape: https://www.payscape.com/mobile-payments.php

It should be noted, that hardly any (if any at all) of these payment gateway services will be free. You'll often find that you'll pay a monthly charge, or a monthly charge + % of transactions, or just a % of each transaction, that'll have to be something you research yourself, and decide upon.

As for accepting payment in your application, well, each payment gateway I've listed, will have an API and various examples on how to implement such things, so I wont go in to detail, plus, I don't want to do all the work for you! ;)

Failing that, if none of the info I've listed above is any help to you, might I suggest: "mobile payment gateways with api" as a starting Google search. Brought up hundreds of results. Can't guarantee that any of good, well known or indeed reliable, but that'll be something you'll have to find out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Payment Service Provider. Also think about other solutions like PayPal.

For other solutions I named PayPal, and it also depends in which country are you operating. For example in Germany you can use Click&Buy. The advantage of this approach is that users can pay simply by following several clicks (after login). Of course the PSP is a paid service. From technical perspective most of the providers offer some kind of REST api, so in the simplest words, the payment happens by HTTP redirects and backend HTTP callbacks.

Comment: Hi@barti how to get a payment service provider?Its free or cost

Comment: For other solutions I named PayPal, and it also depends in which country are you operating. For example in Germany you can use Click&Buy. The advantage of this approach is that users can pay simply by following several clicks (after login). Of course the PSP is a paid service. From technical perspective most of the providers offer some kind of REST api, so in the simplest words, the payment happens by HTTP redirects and backend HTTP callbacks.

Comment: @barti: Always add the content to your answer, don't use comments because comments get deleted in future. Comments are temporary, meant to be used to get further clarification from the author. As you are new to the site, I understand you may not be aware of this. For now, I edited it into your answer. Good luck!